# React Native & Socket.io - cannot establish connection between app and server

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io, react-native

I am building a chat app for android using **React Native** & **Socket.io**.
The issue is that I can't establish a connection between the app and the server. It gives me a connection error saying ***Websocket Error***.

I tried changing the App Socket Io URI to  *`localhost: port`* (this gives transport error or timeout error),  *`ip: port`* (this gives Websocket error), set diff options. Then tried using require *syntaxes* instead of *import* for the server. Then installed older versions `React-native` and `socket.io` & `socket.io-client`, still no luck! Then found an app repo from [github](https://github.com/Hyllesen/TaxiApp/tree/01_SocketIoChat), installed it, and tried running the app. same error. Also changed `cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"` in Android manifest file.

Node: v12.13.0

Testing on external devices:

- Moto E3(1s gen) -Android 6 Marshmallow.
- Redmi Note 7 Pro -Android 9 Pie

### [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVvBN.png)

> **SERVER:**

```
    import express, { Application } from 'express';
    import { createServer } from 'http';
    import { listen, Server } from 'socket.io';
    
    // set port number
    const port = 7777;
    
    // set express
    const app: Application = express();
    
    // set express server
    const server = createServer(app);
    
    // listen express server updates on socket.io
    const io: Server = listen(server, {
        transports: ['websocket'],
        serveClient: false,
    });
    
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log('connection is made');
        socket.emit('commEvent', { data: 'connectionSuccessful' });
        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('connection disconnected');
        });
        socket.on('new-message', (data) => {
            console.log(data.message);
        });
    });
    
    // listen server updates on specified port
    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log('Message app server listening on port:', port);
    });
```

> **SERVER:** *package.json*

```
{
  "name": "message_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Message app server.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node build/index.js",
    "watch": "nodemon src/index.ts",
    "test": "none",
    "build": "npm run lint && tsc-p",
    "lint": "eslint --fix --ext .ts ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5"
  }
}
```

---

> **APP:**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {AppScreenStackNavProps} from '../../../Routes/App/AppRouteTypes';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import HomeRoutes from '../../../Routes/Home/HomeRoute';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

export const socket = io('http://192.168.1.38:7777', {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  jsonp: false,
});

socket.on('commEvent', (data: {data: string}) => {
  console.warn(data.data);
});

const HomeScreen = ({navigation}: AppScreenStackNavProps<'Home'>) => {
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerShown: false,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.connect();
    socket.on('connect', (con: any) => {
      console.debug('SOCKET: connected to socket server', con);
    });
    socket.on('error', (err: any) => {
      console.debug('SOCKET: errors ', err);
    });
    socket.on('connect_error', (err: any) => {
      console.debug('SOCKET: connect_error ---> ', err);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <HomeRoutes />
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
export default HomeScreen;
```

> **APP:** *package.json*

```
{
  "name": "message_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Message app server.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node build/index.js",
    "watch": "nodemon src/index.ts",
    "test": "none",
    "build": "npm run lint && tsc-p",
    "lint": "eslint --fix --ext .ts ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "https-localhost": "^4.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Same issue, Did you find an answer?

Comment: Nope, I couldn't find any soln for this. I ended up hosting the server on Heroku and using it here in place of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I spend a day on this issue what i find is the problem is with your module you installed.

That means if you use typescript in your project make sure to add .d.ts file also for the "socket.io.client" module.

or use this same code in javascript.